# Using AnyObject Type from Parse and access object in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

In parse first i used to get `AnyObject` from its method and i can access all the objects from there using objectForKey method. But now `AnyObject` is changed to `Any`.

```
 PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: apiName.rawValue, withParameters: paramsDict) { (object, error) in
            completion(object, error as? NSError)
        }
```

Now here object on completion in of Type Any and i access it like

```
(object as AnyObject).object(forKey: "cleanPref") as? Bool
```

which don't seem to be proper and if i use Any Type then there i need to do it like

```
if let object = object as? [String: Any] {
 if let pref = object["cleanPref"] as? Bool {
   }
}
```

Is is correct way to do it? Any other solution to keep the AnyObject then Any because there is lot of code needs to be changed if i migrate AnyObject to Any.

Comment: Yes, it is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it´s better to do as you have done but, but I would have changed thing:

Instead of:

```
if let pref = object["cleanPref"] as? Bool {
}
```

Use:

```
guard let pref = object["cleanPref"] as? Bool else { // Some error }
```

You could also add multiple conditions:

```
guard let pref = object["cleanPref"] as? Bool,
      let test = object["test"] as? String else { // Some error }
```